# AWS: will multiple IP addressed and ENI be attached to RDS when specifying multiple subnets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, subnet

If I create an RDS in this way, do the newly created RDS have two IP addresses and two Elastic Network Interfaces(ENI)?

1. create a subnet group with two subnets
2. create an RDS with this newly created subnet group.

[image]

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear about why you need two AZs and subnets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No **it does not**. The multiple subnets are used for **fail-over** setup. So your RDS instance will be created in only one subnet with one IP address. If you have [multi-AZ](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/multi-az/) enabled, the second subnet will be used for a stand-by instance.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Documentation: [Create a DB subnet group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#USER_VPC.CreateDBSubnetGroup)

> When you create a DB instance in a VPC, make sure to choose a DB subnet group. Amazon RDS chooses `a subnet` and `an IP address` within that subnet to associate with your DB instance. Amazon RDS creates and associates an Elastic Network Interface to your DB instance with that IP address. The DB instance uses the Availability Zone that contains the subnet. For Multi-AZ deployments, defining a subnet for two or more Availability Zones in an AWS Region allows Amazon RDS to create a new standby in another Availability Zone should the need arise. You need to do this even for Single-AZ deployments, just in case you want to convert them to Multi-AZ deployments at some point.